# How do I create TextBox input with an icon add-on with TwitterBootstrapMVC?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an input textbox for a login page defined as

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email address"})
    </div>
</div>
```

So, basically a text input box which is pre-appended with a FontAwesome icon.  How do I achieve the same result using TwitterBootstrapMVC5?  The following is a starting point:

```
@f.FormGroup().TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName).ShowValidationMessage(false).Placeholder("Email Address").Label().Class("sr-only input-sm")
```

But without the required pre-appended icon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be very easy in the end:

```
@(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName).Placeholder("Email address").PrependIcon("fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"))
```

gave me the result I was after.